# google compute engine , additional disk not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

we have google compute engine ,  our disk (hard disk) size has full, so we added an additional disk, I followed all steps but still, size has not increased,
please help what might the case.
`its showing error message like " mnt/disks/disk-1  is not mounted completely or it is not available`"

Comment: Adding an additional disk will not increase the size of your existing mounted filesystems. The instructions for resizing an existing disk can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd

Answer (score 0):

If your boot disk is full, you want to [resize the boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd). Please keep in mind that if the disk is too full (100%), the OS will not be able to update the partition table to increase the size if the partition despite the larger disk.

If this is the case, take a [snapshot of the disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots), create a new, larger, disk and then use that as your new boot disk.